# Customizing GET method using Flask Restless

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-restless

I am developing a REST API using [Flask Restless](https://flask-restless.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).

The following code is a sample to illustrate my problem:

```
class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.Unicode)
    password = db.Column(db.String(20))

class Message(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    text = db.Column(db.Unicode)
    recipients = db.relationship("User")

# ...

manager.create_api(User,
    include_columns=['id', 'name'], # password is excluded
    methods=['GET', 'POST'])
manager.create_api(Message, methods=['GET', 'POST'])
```

When I send a GET request to get a user, the API returns his id and his name but not the password since passwords are excluded:

```
{
    "id": 14,
    "name": John
}
```

But when I send a GET request to get a message, I get the full recipient, including the password:

```
{
    "id": 637,
    "text": "Hello!",
    "recipients": [
        {
            "id": 98,
            "name": "Peter",
            "password": "1a52dca635fee"
        }
    ]
}
```

The password should not be returned obviously...

**How can I choose which fields of related models are returned?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [custom serialization](http://flask-restless.readthedocs.org/en/latest/customizing.html#custom-serialization) part of the documentation and [Marshmallow library](https://marshmallow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).

Answer (score 1):

Since you're requesting a message, you would need to define what columns to exclude on that API endpoint:

```
manager.create_api(Message,
  methods=['GET', 'POST'],
  exclude_columns=['recipients.password'])
```

Comment: This answer should be the best answer !